# In behaviors, how should I get the window type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
<behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
    <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StarWindowLoad}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={ RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
    </behaviors:EventTrigger>
</behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I defined an loaded event in the Window

In ViewModel,

```
public ICommand StarWindowLoad
    {
        get => new DelegateCommand<object>(StarWindowLoadDo);
    }

    private void StarWindowLoadDo(object obj)
    {
        SetServerIPAndPort();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (!OpenClien())
            {
                ReOpenClien();
                (obj as Window).DialogResult = true;
            }
            (obj as Window).DialogResult = true;
        });
    }
```

The obj I got is null
After trying many methods, it doesn't work. What should I do to get the window type correctly? thank!

Comment: Thanks in advance！It work！I have tried the solution you gave before, I don’t know why it works nowThank you！！！@Clemens

Comment: oops,I checked it carefully and found that it doesn’t seem to be of Window type, 
     'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.InvokeCommandAction' to type 'System.Windows.Window'

Comment: I want to make a startup window, so I need to pass the Window type to start MainWindow,App.xaml.cs  ' if (Container.Resolve<StarView>().ShowDialog() == false){Application.Current?.Shutdown(); }  else base.InitializeShell(shell);'

Comment: I try to pass Window type in CommandParameter in Button '''CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={ RelativeSource  AncestorType=Window}}''', I don’t know why xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" can’t pass window type

Comment: Try an ElementName Binding with e.g. `x:Name="window"` on the Window and `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window}"`

Comment: All right!!Thank you!!! @Clemens